# Is it possible to dynamically show different themes for different users?

Tags: themes

I have a website that I need to show slightly different content and color scheme to different groups.

Is it possible to show different users a different theme simultaneously?
So if I send a link to User A) and User B) with a separate _GET value of the theme in the URL, can they both see different themes in the same second?

Comment: I don't have enough time to flush out a full answer, but there are filters you can use for this. Check out [this article](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/switch_theme-vs-theme-switching) and the codebase of [this plugin](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/front-end-theme-preview/trunk/fetp.php) to see examples.